# Seleccionar un solo registro de aquellos que tienen varios campos duplicados

Tags: sql, teradata

Buenas, tengo la siguiente estructura en una base de datos

```
 COD_ENTIDAD     COD_IDCONTRA          COD_CONCEGES   COD_PRODGEST
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   0182    00000000000000000000000003     403Q        00126057 
2   0182    00000000000000000000000004     101AW       012600000
3   0182    00000000000000000000000004     403Q        012600000
4   0182    00000000000000000000000004     403Q        00126057 
5   0182    00000000000000000000000004     322C        012600000
6   0182    00000000000000000000000005     322C        012600000
7   0182    00000000000000000000000006     101AW       012600000
```

Quiero seleccionar todos los registros, pero aquellos que tengan los campos **COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA y COD_CONCEGES** iguales, seleccionar uno sólo. Por ejemplo en la tabla de arriba, me quedaría sólo con los registros 1, 2, 3, (el 4 lo salto porque los 3 campos mencionados son iguales al registro 3), 5, 6 y 7

No sé como plantearlo la verdad, no se me ocurre qué cláusula podría usar o qué hacer. Quizás con TOP o subqueries pero no sé plantearlo.
He probado con un join pero obviamente me quedo igual que estaba, porque me quedo con todos los registros.

```
SELECT A.*, B.COD_PRODGEST FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA, COD_CONCEGES
FROM BBDD) A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA, COD_CONCEGES, COD_PRODGEST
FROM BBDD) B
ON A.COD_ENTIDAD= B.COD_ENTIDAD
AND A.COD_IDCONTRA = B.COD_IDCONTRA
AND A.COD_CONCEGES = B.COD_CONCEGES
```

¿Alguna idea o pista de como podría hacerlo?

Comment: cuál motor de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: Hola @Lamak utilizo Teradata

Comment: Hola @McNets perdón por el error, concepto es cod_conceges. Gracias

Comment: @DevCodeG cómo eliges uno de los registros duplicados por sobre el otro?, cuál es el criterio?

Comment: @Lamak, es indiferente, con quedarme con uno cualquiera vale, de ahí que pensé meter de alguna forma un TOP 1 para quedarme con el primero que me devolviera de los duplicados, pero no sabría como meterlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te da lo mismo cuál registro duplicado es el que seleccionas, entonces puedes probar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  A.*, 
                B.COD_PRODGEST, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.COD_ENTIDAD, A.COD_IDCONTRA, A.COD_CONCEGES
                                  ORDER BY COD_ENTIDAD) AS RN
        FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA, COD_CONCEGES
                FROM BBDD) A
        INNER JOIN (SELECT COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA, COD_CONCEGES, COD_PRODGEST
                    FROM BBDD) B
            ON A.COD_ENTIDAD= B.COD_ENTIDAD
            AND A.COD_IDCONTRA = B.COD_IDCONTRA
            AND A.COD_CONCEGES = B.COD_CONCEGES) X
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lamak ! Ya funciona! Excelente respuesta. Lo único que hay que indicar en el partition el alias de la subquery porque sino da error por campos ambiguos.

Comment: @DevCodeG Toda la razón, ya actualicé la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas devolver es tan solo los campos COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA y COD_CONCEGES de una tabla, la consulta quedaría tal que así

```
SELECT DISTINCT (COD_ENTIDAD, COD_IDCONTRA, COD_CONCEGES) FROM Nombre_de_tabla
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Pero el op quiere todas las columnas, simplemente quedarse con una de las que se repite entre estas 3 columnas

Comment: Hola @CecilioAlonso, no me sirve, no es lo que pido. Gracias

Answer (score -2):

Puedes hacerlo con el comando `DISTINCT` y seria algo como esto:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myTable WHERE 1 = 1
```

En tu caso seria algo como

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.COD_PRODGEST FROM 
( /* Tu subquery aquí */)
WHERE 1= 1
```

Prueba y comenta si funcionó.

Saludos

Comment: Esta consulta entregará el mismo resultado que posteó el op

Comment: El tiene el Distict dentro de los subquerys, por eso al hacer el inner join se vuelve a duplicar, al hacerlo de manera externa ya deberia quedar bien, o tambien puede usar el distict en el campo especifico que quiere que no se duplique.

Comment: no, incorrecto. Si ves el resultado, se nota que la combinación de los valores es única, el `distinct` no hará nada

Comment: @Lamak Tienes razón, tengo la culpa, no puse el comando donde debería. Ya corregí la respuesta

Comment: Tu cambio no traerá ninguna diferencia, la verdad

Comment: Hola @EzequieleezzeklCanul a cuál te refieres con mi subquery, tendria que meter en los paréntesis la query del join que tengo en el ejemplo? He  modificado mi query añadiendo el distinct arriba y el where al final pero me da todos los resultados

Comment: Como dice @Lamak no trae diferencia, me siguen saliendo los mismos registros, no me quedo sólo con 1 de los que tienen los tres primeros campos iguales.